# PostgreSQL: get advisory lock unless more than n transactions are waiting for it

Tags: postgresql, postgres-10

I've a resource that gets acquired from distributed clients. This resource is protected by a transaction level lock:

> SELECT pg_advisory_xact_lock(123456)

I know I can use `pg_try_advisory_xact_lock` if I don't want to wait for it to be free. If I got it - the call would return `true`, otherwise `false`.

What I would like to achieve is the behaviour of `pg_advisory_xact_lock` with queue-size. If less than 4 transactions are waiting from the lock join them in waiting, otherwise return false `pg_try_advisory_xact_lock` otherwise. If you managed to get the lock - return true.

Can I achieve this without writing a plv8 extension? Any ideas?

I'm using PostgreSQL 10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cycle through "pg_try_advisory_xact_lock(...)" on 5 different lock ids (say 123457 to 123461) (1 real lock holder and 4 more non-holding waiters = 5).  Getting one of those then grants you the right to wait on the "real" lock id.  Failing to get any of the 5 results in failure.  This does mean you have to reserve/coordinate 6 magic constants, rather than 1.